# How to add rewrite rule in WordPress to serve images in custom plugin folder

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a custom plugin for WordPress which requires to assess images in the folder of my custom plugin. For simplicity, i can just use wp_plugin_url to access the images required in my code. However, I wonder that might impose security vulnerability in which the plugin folder path will be available in plain text. I was thinking to achieve the purpose using rewrite rules of WordPress. My questions are how exactly rewrite rules can use to serve static images in my custom plugin folder and is there any other option for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using images from plugin folder has no security vulnerability and is a common practice. Please note that you do not expose plugin path. Just for example.

Plugin path on server:

`/var/www/my-wp-site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin`

Plugin url:

`http://my-site.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin`

Path and url are different and have only common ending. Knowing url gives nothing to the attacker.

Comment: With the plugin url will others be able to access other folders or files in the plugin?

Comment: I thought I have explained. Nobody can access files and folders on the server just knowing some urls.